# Why the function printf("%s",c) in C doesn't work in Clion? How can I distinguish between '\n' and EOF while pressing enter

Tags: clion

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8Zhq.png)

If I enter some words for a few lines and then press "Enter" for two times then the codes end without any output.
Beginner really needs help!

Comment: Voted to close: your code should go in the question itself (with lines starting by four spaces). Using an image is bad manners here in this case.

Comment: Ok Thank you for your comment! But I am still confused about the point since the code is not created by me but from a textbook for C language.I just don't know why it is not working?

Comment: You should have used your debugger. And you probably made a typo when copying the code, or your textbook is so bad that you should take another one.

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to the compiler you are using, but to your [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) implementation. The behavior is likely to stay the same if you change your compiler.

You should take more time in studying the [C language](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and the functions of its standard library.

`<stdio.h>` functions are [buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) (and that is why they are efficient: making a [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) for every output character is very slow).

By default, *stdout* is usually line-buffered (when it is a terminal at least). See also [setvbuf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf).

So you should either terminate your control format string for `printf` with `\n` or *explicitly* call [fflush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush)

BTW, notice that POSIX specifies a [getline](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) function. On a POSIX system, you'll better use it instead of defining some `GetLine` one of similar functionality.

Also, take the good habit to enable all warnings and debug info in your *compiler* (notice that Clion is not your compiler, but an IDE which is running some compiler). If using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. With [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) compile with `clang -Wall -g`. Improve the code till you get no warnings. Then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`) to run your code step by step and query the program state.

Notice also that `(int)"\n"` (not the same as `(int)'\n'`) is very likely to be wrong (and you can't easily predict its value, e.g. because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)) because it is converting the address of some constant literal into an integer (which is in practice meaningless).

Kernighan & Ritchie wrote an excellent [textbook](http://www.cprogramming.com/books/ritchie.html) on C.